# WebSphere7 classloading Issues

Tags: websphere

I am just wondering, if the below is possible with Websphere or not?

I have an Enterprise application using Websphere 7 and with PARENT_LAST classloading mode. I am now trying to use a third party feature namely, gemfire in the application. My application with gemfire runs perfectly in PARENT_FIRST classloading mode. But, I can see some linkage errors occuring because of PARENT_LAST setting. Temperarly, I could solve them by removing the classes that are conflicting from gemfire jar(By this, I am actually asking those removed classes to be loaded from web app server). But, I am not sure if this will create some bigger issues as my appliaction grow to its fullest.

My question is : Suppose we have abc.jar in both web app server and also in gemfire.jar, with PARENT_LAST loading mode.Is it possible to solve the above class conflicts by not removing any class files from jars, instead tell the classloading mechanism to use the class loaded from web app server at a particular case and use the same class loaded from gemfire jar(meaning load from application) at another case?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. We are using a similar setup. You should be very careful though and only use the exact same jars (or at least the same classes) in all the places you need to have them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please elaborate on how can I insist on loading same class by differnt classloaders and use the appropriate class when required?

Comment: One more question : In my case with gemfire in my enterprise application with PARENT_LAST classloading mode, Do you think deletenig the class files from gemfire.jar that are also existing in web app server(By which asking them to be loaded from web app server)will create problems in future? My take on this question is, no it will not create any problem because if I use PARENT_FIRST they will any way be loaded from web app server even if I keep the classes in gem fire without deleting. What are your comments on this?

Comment: With PARENT_LAST you should really be ok as long as all the classes you are using are also in the application. With PARENT_FIRST it is harder to know (sometimes it has loaded the class from other applications), then you should only deploy it as one shared library and use it across your applications.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please elaborate on how to can i insist on loading same class by different classloaders and use the appropriate class when required?

Comment: If at all possible, don't ever use two different versions of the same class. Otherwise PARENT_LAST and including the correct class with the application should do the trick.